# Strong name signing after build

Tags: c#, .net, strongname

What I am trying to do:

1. build my assembly Main.dll which references RefA.dll and RefB.dll
2. merge into a single Main.dll assembly using IlMerge
3. Strong name sign it as a post build process.

Step 3 will happen only for an official build on a build machine where the strong name signature is stored in a container (using: `sn.exe -i <myfile.snk> mycontainer`)

I don't find a way to perform step 3: sn.exe seems to allow only re-signing a signed assembly or a delay signed assembly.

Am I missing something?

Note that IlMerge.exe (available on NuGet, version 2.14.1208) only takes a file instead of a key container. IlMerge source code seems to have progressed and support keycontainer switch argument.

Comment: ilmerge lets you specify a key container using `/keycontainer:containername`

Comment: Really? It's not documented and it's not working.

Comment: Yes.  Are you using the most recent version?  The unit tests for this functionality are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge/blob/master/ILMerge.Tests/KeyTests.cs).

Comment: version 2.14.1208 from NuGet

Comment: error is Ignoring unknown option: 'keycontainer:my_container'